# Wordpress > How to remove the default pages (about, hello world) via script

Tags: wordpress

[Update: I've found the API reference. The method used is below]

```
<?php wp_delete_post( $postid, $force_delete = false ) ?>
```

I've got a wordpress plugin that creates my default pages for me (about us, contact us, privacy policy, etc) when I first install a new wordpress site. It works really well and gives me a quick boost to rapidly build the site.

However, one problem I have is that I still have to manually remove the default wordpress page (about) and post ("hello world") as well as enable Akismet.

I'd like to add these functions to my plugin.

My question:

Assuming I'm deleting by ID, can I reasonably depend on the default ids for these pages to remain constant from site to site and host to host? (*ie, has anyone found that their are differences in various web host wordpress installers that would create different IDs for these pages*)

Otherwise, I suppose I could delete based on the page title matching "About" and "Hello World". It is a brand new site, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess / assume IDs are the same on new installations by default. (but might be safer to delete based on title).

You could auto-enable plugins, but sometimes you want to use a different wordpress.com account (API key) to activate your Akismet. Recent Akismet keys can also be obtained by email - so you might perhaps want to change them from time to time or for different projects.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Tom. I've located the API docs here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post
The command is <?php wp_delete_post( $postid, $force_delete = false ) ?>